# Sqlite conflict occurred between two projects of same solution

Tags: windows-phone-8, sqlite

I getting issue while adding Sqlite-net and Sqlite-net-wp8 on two projects of same solution

> Error:Warning 219 The type 'SQLite.AsyncTableQuery' in
>   'd:\Repository\code\WindowsPhone8\DataContext\SQLiteAsync.cs'
>   conflicts with the imported type 'SQLite.AsyncTableQuery' in
>   'd:\Repository\code\WindowsPhone8\Model\Bin\x86\Debug\Model.dll'.
>   Using the type defined in
>   'd:\Repository\code\WindowsPhone8\DataContext\SQLiteAsync.cs'.    d:\repository\code\windowsphone8\datacontext\sqliteasync.cs 317 10  DataContext

I have created 1 solution for performing database operation and another for the datamodel, I have added Sqlite reference for adding primarykey and Autoincrement in datamodel project but I am getting above error

Same Version of Dll I have added in both project, I am not able to understand does this occur

Please help me

Comment: Had any success with this error?

Comment: yes, we have to delete it from one solution that's dependent to second